# CMD script Malfunctioning

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a cmd script that simply runs a windows 7 custom theme-pack (you can download it  [here](http://1drv.ms/1LdlfXe).)
 The file can be downloaded [here](http://1drv.ms/1H3gZYE) 
Whenever I run it, the files malfunctions (read below for a description of the malfunctioning)

## The file's contents

```
echo off
color a
title "System Shutdown Manager"
cls
start C:\Users\Jeremi\OneDrive\Happy_files\Movie,Audio,Photo\themese\derp-o-nutz.themepack
shutdown -s -t 00 -c "Shutdown Manager in process."
exit
```

#### When I run it on windows 7:

The cmd file seems to re-open itself

The number of personalization windows grow rapidly

It will not shutdown the computer

It will not exit the file.

#### When I run it on windows 8.1 :

The cmd file rarely re-open

The number of personalization windows grow rapidly

It will not shutdown the computer

I get a message: "Windows can't save this theme to your computer" (But yet it does open the theme)

It will not exit the file.

The messages spread like wildfire.

Despite the fact I have 'Always Combine, Hide Labels' on It will give each message it's own Window

### Important Notes:

The message does not come up when I manually open the file.

The path is correct and the file is not corrupt

The theme pack is open but from that point nothing happens

If I don't close the file in time on windows 8.1, the system will crash and I will have to force shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your batch file is called `shutdown.cmd`, so the line

```
shutdown -s -t 00 -c "Shutdown Manager in process."
```

will make the batch file call itself.

Rename the batch file or change the line that calls shutdown to

```
shutdown.exe -s -t 00 -c "Shutdown Manager in process."
```